# Erro ao Instalar dependências no projeto NODE

Tags: node.js

Estou tendo problemas em uma aplicação node. 
Quando tento instalar os pacotes, dependências gera-se um erro, quanto tento instalar o express. segue o erro:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Desenvolvimento\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-28T14_41_03_239Z-debug.log

Alguém já passou por isso, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: 1. O que o arquivo de log informado na mensagem está dizendo? 2. `Unexpected end of JSON input` é um erro que ocorre quando tenta-se fazer o parse de um JSON mal formado, muito provavelmente este não é um erro com o express. Dê uma verificada no seu package.json, possivelmente ele não está correto.

Comment: Obrigado Renato Gama, consegui solucionar o problema, havia um problema de sintaxe no meu package, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Provavelmente o seu package.json está com algum erro de sintaxe. Verifique se está tudo certo nele, e por via das dúvidas remova a pasta do node_modules.

Comment: verifica o package.json, esse erro indica que tem erro de formatação lá